# Get outlook Active window handle hwnd in C#

Tags: c#, outlook, sendmessage, hwnd

I want to get the outlook Active window handle (hwnd) in C#. I want to use this for SendMessage() method which takes hwnd as first parameter. Outlook is open and not minimized. Tried to do like this..
dynamic winHwnd= Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow();
Not working as type mismatches . Even if i convert it doesn't work. Could some one suggest me to get this handler..

Comment: Are you doing this from within your plugin which has been loaded by Outlook or by some other external application?

Comment: Yes . I am doing within my outlook add-in which is been loaded by outlook.I have a button the the ribbon . this button is a drop down button and i am able to get the control of the button but not able to execute. So i thought i can perform a mouse click i.e WM_LBUTTONDOWN in sendmessage()  method. For that i want the outlook handler.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use the GetActiveWindow api function.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetActiveWindow();

IntPtr handle = GetActiveWindow();
```

Try and minimize the window to see if you are getting the correct handle.

```
private const int SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow)

ShowWindowAsync(hWnd, SW_SHOWMINIMIZED);
```

Comment: I did this. When i debug handle has some value but when i send this handle in SendMessage() method to click the button it is not happening. Do i have to take to button control also which is in ribbon.

Comment: @SoumyaChiniwar Updated answer on how to minimise a window based on the handle received. You can use this to test if you have received the correct handle.

Comment: Yes i tried with what you said. It is having the correct handler. It is minimizing the window. I want to click on button that is on ribbon. Can you suggest me how to i perform that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try to use generic approach by using system Api FindWindow to get the window you interested by it's name:

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
 static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

 IntPtr hWnd = (IntPtr)FindWindow(windowName, null);
```

From ActiveWindow you could try:

```
dynamic activeWindow = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow();
    IntPtr outlookHwnd = new OfficeWin32Window(activeWindow).Handle;
```

Comment: I don't have to find window because we already have handler. Is there a way to do with ActiveWindow() which actually has the outlook handler?

Comment: I tired this i don't find OfficeWin32Window . Instead i used ' IntPtr windowHandle = new IWin32Window(win).Handle;' which is throwing me error --- "Cannot create an instances of abstract class".

Comment: try implementation from here: https://github.com/JakeGinnivan/VSTOContrib/blob/master/src/VSTOContrib.Core/OfficeWin32Window.cs

Comment: I already have a add-in . Inside which i am getting the control of a button using redemption. Thing is it is a drop down item and i cannot perform execute() on it. I want to do mouse click using WM_LBUTTONDOWN.

Answer (score -1):

Cast the Inspector object to the IOleWindow interface and call IOleWindow::GetWindow. The same will work for the Explorer object.

Comment: I am getting error while doing `dynamic activeWindow = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow();
        IOleWindow win = activeWindow as IOleWindow;
        window = win.GetWindow();` getting error at IOleWindow. Do i have to import anything?

Comment: Compile error or run-time error? What is it? You can either get the IOleWindow interface definition from http://www.getcodesamples.com/src/3A684D44/2233A502 or add Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop to the uses clause.

Comment: Compile time. type or namespace could not be found.

Comment: Have you tried either suggestion from my previous reply?

Comment: Yeah i have added the interface its not working. the variable has null value

Comment: `  dynamic winHandle = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow();   IOleWindow handle = winHandle as IOleWindow;   SendMessage(handle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero); `  handle has null value when i debug and check.

Comment: I have taken control of my drop down button. It is pooping up in window but not executing as it is not visible to API. Do i have to take handle of that button also?

Comment: You never call IOleWindow.GetWindow

Comment: What is not working? It returns an error? You get back 0? SendMessage does not behave as expected?